# n I try to install java, the terminal makes this comment: 'Installing Java on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS

Tags: 16.04, java, firefox-extensions

I am a novice - and I tried to install java on my Ubuntu 16.04 32-bit LTS system, as I needed that for many things.  I followed the instructions I got, very carefully, using a terminal without understanding much of what I was doing, but the system came back with a sad message: "Could not install because of too many errors".

Clearly, I need to clean up - possibly install an update, but I have no idea how to go about that.  I would hate to lose my firefox settings for instance, like bookmarks and passwords, but I cannot find any way of finding where they are stored, much less backing them up, even though I am certain there is a folder somewhere in the system, where those firefox data are stored.  I got my working documents backed up on a remote drive, but all my settings - how do I preserve those through this upcoming ordeal of updating/reinstalling?

And how do I clean up the errors - is there a simpler way than updating/reinstalling?

(I saw a thread about using clonezilla, but I did not understand anything of that - it was too technical, and it appeared to me that it would not work on my 32-bit system...).

Thanks in advance for any help with this!

Comment: Backup firefox data : `tar cf mozilla-backup.tar .mozilla`, where .mozilla/ is a hidden folder in "/home/[name]/".  ... Install java : `sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk`

Comment: @Knud Larsen - Could you please translate that to Danish or English?  I honestly don't understand much of it...

Comment: `tar cf mozilla-backup.tar .mozilla/` is a command to do in /home/[user-name]/ to get a backup of all firefox settings. ( The settings are stored in the hidden folder `.mozilla/`) .... Install the default java : The full command is : `sudo apt update && sudo apt install openjdk-8-jdk` .... If you have any errors, they must be added to your original question : The 'edit' button.

Comment: The edity button does not allow me to make more than one line - that does not help anyone...

Comment: And how am I going to find those hidden settings again?

Comment: I cannot attach a screen shot of the terminal output, but it is generally saying that it does not complete the installation because of errors.  It does not specify what errors.

Comment: I am close to giving up - this is too technical for me.  And this site is full of restrictions I do not understand either.  I have no idea what to do.

Comment: "...a command to do in /home/[user-name]/ " - and what does that mean?  What is "/home/[user-name]/"?

Comment: Under "Home" are these folders: deja-dup, Deshtop, Documents, Downloads, dwhelper, Music, Pictures, Public, Templates, Videos, Examples - and nothing more.  I did not create them, and I deleted nothing in that folder.

Comment: The location command is `$ pwd`, which will show you that "Home" = `/home/[user-name]` . Hidden files / dot-files are *hidden*, invisible. Can be seen when `View → 'Show hidden files'` is selected. Or with the `ls  -la` command.

Comment: pwd gives  "command not found" in terminal.  There is no "View" option in the many anywhere I can find. The ls -la command gave a list I do not understand anything of and it changes nothing in   the settings for how I can see files, so it is of no help.